# Pandas read_hdf: how to get column names when using chunksize or iterator?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdf5, chunking

I'm reading in a large (~10 GB) hdf5 table with pandas.read_hdf. I'm using iterator=True so that I can access chunks at a time (e.g., chunksize=100000 rows at a time).

How do I get a list of all the column names or 'keys'?

Also, how come there is no get_chunk method analogous to the one for pandas.read_table? Is directly iterating over the chunks the only way ("for chunk in data: "), and you can't access different numbered chunks at will ("data[300]")?

Edit:

Looks like I can access the column names with a loop that breaks after accessing the first chunk:

```
for i,v in enumerate(data):
if i != 0:
    break
colnames = v.columns
```

But then my second question still remains: is there no way to access each individual chunk on the pandas TextFileReader iterator (e.g., mimicking the get_chunk method of read_table, or with a dict-like lookup, data[0]), instead of doing the above weird single-iteration for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried loading the HDF5 file as an `HDFStore`?  That would allow you to use the [`HDFStore.select`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.select.html) method which may do what you want (with seeking, etc.).  You can use `select` to only operate on a subset of columns too.  To me it just looks like it provides more flexibility than the `read_hdf` function.  The following might help as long as you know the structure of your HDF5 file:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('/path/to/file', 'r')
colnames = store.select('table_key', stop=1).columns

# iterate over table chunks
chunksize = 100000
chunks = store.select('table_key', chunksize=chunksize)
for chunk in chunks:
    ...code...

# select 1 specific chunk as iterator
chunksize = 100000
start, stop = 300*chunksize, 301*chunksize
this_chunk = store.select('table_key', start=start, stop=stop, iterator=True)
do_work(this_chunk)

store.close()
```

Note that you can also open an HDFStore as a context manager, e.g.,

```
with pd.HDFStore('/path/to/file', 'r') as store:
    ...code...
```